# System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'F' is an invalid start of a value. (sockets in C#)

Tags: c#, json

im trying to make a program where you have client and server connected with a socket in C# .net 5.0.
In the beginning it works sending objects over a socket but after a while I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'F' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'F' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at LibClient.SimpleClient.start() in C:\Users\---\OneDrive\Documenten\GitHub\Courses\Networking\DistLibrary\LibClient\Client.cs:line 134
   at LibClientSimulator.ClientsSimulator.startSimulation() in C:\Users\---\OneDrive\Documenten\GitHub\Courses\Networking\DistLibrary\LibClient\Program.cs:line 62
   at LibClientSimulator.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\---\OneDrive\Documenten\GitHub\Courses\Networking\DistLibrary\LibClient\Program.cs:line 100
```

this is the client

```
while (true)
{
    int b = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, b);
    Message message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Message>(data);   //Error happens here
                
    if(data != null)
    {
        if(message.Type == MessageType.Welcome)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            Console.WriteLine($"Message From Server: {message.Type}");
            message.Type = MessageType.BookInquiry;
            message.Content = bookName;

            jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
            msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString);

            clientSocket.Send(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the line in the server side which triggers the error:

```
Message message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Message>(data);
//Message messageFromBookhelper = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Message>(databookhelper);

if (message.Type == MessageType.Hello)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{message.Content}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Message from Client: {message.Type}\n");
                        message.Type = MessageType.Welcome;
                        message.Content = "";
    msg1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(message));
    newSock.Send(msg1);
}
else if(message.Type == MessageType.BookInquiry)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Book requested from client: {message.Content}");
    RequestedBook = message.Content;
    Booksock.Connect(BookHelperEndpoint);
    message.Type = MessageType.BookInquiry;
    message.Content = RequestedBook;
    msg1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(message));
                        Booksock.Send(msg1);
                        int b1 = Booksock.Receive(buffer);
    databookhelper = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, b1);
                     
    Message messageFromBookhelper = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Message>(databookhelper);
    Console.WriteLine(databookhelper);
    BookData bookdata = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BookData>(messageFromBookhelper.Content);
    string bookdataJSON = JsonSerializer.Serialize<BookData>(bookdata);
    Console.WriteLine($"Book from Bookhelper: {bookdataJSON}");

//THIS LINE GIVES ERROR 
    message.Type = MessageType.BookInquiryReply; 
    message.Content = "Hey";
    msg1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(message));
    newSock.Send(msg1);
}

data = null;
newSock.Send(msg);
```

Other messages are fine when it is being sent but when I am sending this last message it suddenly gives that error. I don't know why.

This is what is being received apparently on client through the variable 'data': `{"Type":2,"Content":"Hey"}From server: Your message delivered`

Comment: We need to see an example of the message that caused this error to occur. Most likely, the message is not JSON, but a string that starts with "F"...

Comment: This is what it is sending: ```{"Type":4,"Content":"Hey"}```, if i write in console the serialized JSON before sending it: ```Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(message));```

Comment: What's the content of the `data` variable on the client side just before the error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what is passed into `JsonSerializer.Deserialze` call on line 134 of Client.cs. That is where the error is occurring.

Comment: @pmcoltrane Apparently this is the content: ```{"Type":2,"Content":"Hey"}From server: Your message delivered```

Comment: Well, there's your issue then. You just need to work out where the `From server: Your message delivered` is coming from.

Comment: Thanks guys, i figured it out